# Parsing String for name value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse this inbound email body_text so that is looks like "Employee Start Date":" 2021/09/07"

I'm trying to put the string through a exReg, but can't get it to format correctly. Any suggestions? I have recently updated my script.

thanks!

```
Employee Start Date: 

2021/09/07

Employee ID:

123456789

Employee Preferred Name:

John Doe 

Employee Company:

Global
```

```
var emailObj = {};

    try {
        var valPairs = body_text;

        var regEx = /^(.+):(.+)$/; //Name is everything preceding first :, value everything after.

        var valPairs = body_text.split("\n").filter(function (item) { 
           
            return regEx.test(item);
        });

        var matches; 
        //loop through email body and build object
        for (var i = 0; i < valPairs.length; i++) {
            matches = valPairs[i].match(regEx);
            try {
                emailObj[matches[1].toString().trim()] = matches[2].toString().trim(); //Add trimmed name/val to object
            } catch (ex) {
                gs.error(ex.message);
            }
        }

    } catch (ex) {
        gs.error(ex.message);
    }
    console.log(emailObj)
```

The name value pairs needs to be on on the same line with no line breaks. I need the results to look like this.

```
Employee Start Date: 2021/09/07
Employee ID: 123456789
Employee Preferred Name: John Doe
Employee Company: Global
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't make people guess what's wrong with the current code. Tell them.

Comment: What is a "match" and what would make it validate to true? And what is even doing the validating?

Comment: Since the entire statement is a a string, I have a regEx checking for key before : and the value after :, if its on the same line. For some reason, I can't get a line break after each name value pair. The valPairs checks for the validation once its sees a line break. if the match = true, it will loop all of the objects into a json array, so I can call the object by the key.

Comment: Email string doesn't have a new line character, so it will never find one. Also, you don't have commas between different key value pairs, so it will not get what you want.

Comment: Is there anyway to add the commas with replace?

Comment: You don't have a way to tell where the comma's should be, so I don't think so. You will most likely have to do it during the email cleanup.

Comment: what if the original raw box_text was 

Employee Start Date:<br> <br>

2021/09/07 <br> <br>

Employee ID:<br> <br>

123456789 <br> <br>

Employee Preferred Name:<br> <br>

John Doe <br> <br>

Employee Company: <br> <br>

Global<br> <br>

my other option is to have it formatted like


Employee Start Date: 2021/09/07 <br>
Employee ID: 123456789 <br>
Employee Preferred Name: John Doe <br> 
Employee Company: Global <br>

Comment: If there will always be a value for each key, then you should be able to do it.

Comment: yes, there will always be a value for each key. If I can get the correct .replace in place, it would work perfectly. I guess I will have to start from scratch. I couldn't get the formatting correctly to remove a line break between the key and value in the body_text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to format the html better. It also parses it from the JSON string into a jS object.

```js
const email = "Employee Start Date:<br> <br> 2021/09/07 <br> <br> Employee ID:<br> <br> 123456789 <br> <br> Employee Preferred Name:<br> <br> John Doe <br> <br> Employee Company: <br> <br> Global<br> <br>"

function extractData(str) {
  str = str.replace(/(:\s*(?:<br>\s*)+)/gm, '": "');
  str = str.replace(/(\s*(?:<br>\s*)+)/gm, '", "');
  str = str.replace(/(,\s*"$)/gm, '}');
  str = str.replace(/(^)/gm, '{"');
  return JSON.parse(str)
}

console.log(extractData(email))
```

Comment: Thank you! Now we are getting somewhere.

Comment: I thought we had it. It works Visual Studio Code, but unfortunately it didn't work within a client side script within ServiceNow. I get an error "Error: String contains control character,Detail: String contains control character"

Below is what I'm trying to parse. There are an extra line in the inbound email, where the name value pairs has to be on the same line as this format below.
  
Employee Start Date: 2021/08/17


```
Employee Start Date:

2021/08/17

Employee ID:

61028517

Employee Preferred Name:

Dan Chan

Employee Company:

iProspect
```